# Cook top wiring different than outlet wires

Tags: electrical, wiring, kitchens

I recently bought a home and noticed the cook top wiring that was installed was never connected, the wiring from the outlet is Black, White and Red. However, the cook top wires are Black, White and Green. I am confused at how this should be connected. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Brand/model of the cooktop? A picture of the wiring diagram that should be located somewhere on the back/underneath the top of it would be helpful. Pictures of the outlet and the connectors on the cooktop would be good, to. Just [edit] them into your question.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the outlet box please?

Comment: electric cooktop or gas cooktop?

Answer (score 1):

Check the nameplate.  If the cooktop has a 240V voltage, then it's a simple affair: get some [red electrical tape](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Gardner-Bender-1-2-in-x-20-ft-Colored-Electrical-Tape-5-Pack-GTPC-550/100054213) and spiral it around the cooktop's white wire. Now things will make much more sense.

The 240V indicates that both cooktop wires are "hot" wires, and the semi-convention is that one hot is black and the other is red.  However, standard 2-conductor + ground cable is supplied as black-white, which is why this happens.

Comment: The OP noted that the wires “from the outlet” are black, white and red. You should address the lack of a ground wire.